# Can i launch an activity from an external app into a fragment of my own?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Lets say i am building an app called, `myApp`. and i know that on the device is another app called `bobsApp` that has an activity called `bobsApp.someActivity`  lets say in myApp i have an activity with two fragments, `fragA` and `fragB`  am i able to on click from `myApp`, `fragA` launch bobsApp.someActivity into `myApp` `fragB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You only can start the bobsApp, but you can't start the same Activity in your app. This would lead to many security issues.

Comment: Guess I dontbsee the security issue I can launch any activity in to a fragment of an activity.. can you point me to documentation that confirms this?